# Parsing to JSON Error : Unable to invoke no-args constructor

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following class which I want to serialise to JSON then get back as an object :

```
public class CustomerKeys2 {

    protected JAXBElement<String> customerIdPub;

    //getter & setter
}
```

my code for serializing/deserializing is like this

```
CustomerKeys2 customerKeys = new CustomerKeys2();
//getJaxbString just get a JAXBElement<String> from a regular String
customerKeys.setCustomerIdPub(getJaxbString("CustomerIdPub"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(customerKeys);
CustomerKeys2 obj2 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, CustomerKeys2.class);
```

the last line (gson.fromJson) throw the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

This is because customerIdPub is of type JAXBElement and not just a regular String. **The problem is that I cannot modify the class CustomerKeys2**. It is part of an external JAR an I must use it as it.

I already tried other libraries (flexjson, Jackson...) but same error.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: provide constructor into class CustomerKeys2  with no-argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify CustomerKeys2

Comment: Did you try to "*Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type*"?

Comment: yes. same. The problem is that JAXBElement don't have a default constructor, not CustomerKeys2